# Get IP Address of DNS Host Alias

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, dns

My Setup:

ServerName: SV-APP-01.mydomain.com

ServerIP: 192.168.0.190

DNS CNAME Alias: APP Server

My App

Within my App I have configured a Server. This should be my DNS CNAME Alias.
In Order to prevent DNS Issues I want to transfer my DNS Alias Name into the IP Adresse.

Furthermore our Customers should set up a DNS Alias Name and the App saves the IP Adresse into System Preference Option.

So the question is how do I get the IP of an Hostname Alias.

Comment: Suppose the IP address changes but the name remains the same? Don't store the IP address, store the name and resolve it at run time.

Comment: Nevertheless, how do I do that?

Comment: does notbody know how to do that?